# while True in async programming

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I have this function:

```py
async def on_event(event: dict):
    for func in MESSAGE_LISTENERS:
        await func(getMessage(event['data']))
```

and this decorator which appends the function into `MESSAGE_LISTENERS`:

```py
def on_message(func: callable):
    MESSAGE_LISTENERS.append(func)
    return func
```

And this is the code which runs the function `on_event` when a message is received from the server:

```py
async def run(self):
    async with websockets.connect(WS_URL, max_size=None) as ws:
        await self.__on_open(ws)
        while True:
            event = json.loads(await ws.recv())
            await on_event(event)
```

And this is the usage:

```py
client = Client()

@on_message
async def onMessage(msg: Message):
    while True:
        print(f"Message '{msg.content}' was sent by the server")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
       
asyncio.run(client.run())
```

Now, if a message is received from the server, I want the bot to keep printing the message every 3 seconds, but after the the first message is received, the whole instance freezes and won't listen for/detect new messages.

I tried:

```py
async def on_event(event: dict):
    for func in MESSAGE_LISTENERS:
        asyncio.create_task(func(getMessage(event['data'])))
```

but it still freezes.

Comment: I do not see where onMessage is tied into the rest of the script.  You have almost all the ingredients of a minimal reproducible example here - can you turn it into one?  Also,  `on_event` (once you get it working) will loop through all the previous messages, creating for each of those a new task that is a duplicate of one already running.  Is that really your intention?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code, if any, is this line `event = json.loads(await ws.recv())`: it will block the execution in that function (but not the asyncio loop), and will just call `on_event` again whenever a new message gets through the socket. As no new messages get through, `on_event` is not called again.

The way to do is to post new socked-bound messages in a queue, and have yet another function that will keep repeating old messages if that is what you want:

```
import asyncio
...


async def on_event(event: dict):
    for func in MESSAGE_LISTENERS:
        await func(getMessage(event['data']))

async def event_repeater(queue):
    last_event = {"data": "no event received yet"}
    while True:
        try:
            with asyncio.timeout(3):
                 new_event = await queue.get()
        except TimeoutError: 
                 new_event = None
        if new_event:
            last_event = new_event # Replaces the event to be sent with the latest one
        await on_event(last_event)
        
     

async def run(self):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # This will set the event repeater to keep running forever.
    asyncio.create_task(event_repeater(queue))
    async with websockets.connect(WS_URL, max_size=None) as ws:
        await self.__on_open(ws)
        while True:
            event = json.loads(await ws.recv())
            queue.put_nowait(event)
```

Answer (score -1):

i used **await on_event(event)**
and using await, causes the code to wait until on_event returns a value, which it does never return a value soo

Replace **await on_event(event)**
With **on_event(event)**

Comment: Bad idea. If `on_event` is async, you *will need* to await it. However, you might want [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for).

Comment: Please format your code in the back ticks and provide a working solution. This solution does not actually work as you will just return the coroutine without scheduling and running it if the `await` keyword is not used.

Answer (score -1):

Your decorator is not written correctly, so it doesn't do what you think it does.  Decorators should define and return a new function; here you are just returning the same (undecorated) one.  The interpreter will call your "decorator" once as it passes through the script on start-up.

Your code doesn't show where MESSAGE_LISTENERS is defined, but it looks to me like it will contain exactly one element, which gets placed there by the interpreter when it passes through the code.  No other one will ever be added.  I think this is why your script appears to work on the first message and then stop.  It doesn't really stop, but since nothing else ever gets appended to MESSAGE_LISTENERS, no evidence of a second event is ever seen.

Example:

```
def deco1(f):
    print("Decorator 1")
    return f

def deco2(f):
    def f1(*x, **y):
        print("Decorator 2")
        return f(*x, **y)
    return f1

@deco1
def func1(s):
    print(f"Hello 1 {s}")

@deco2
def func2(s):
    print(f"Hello 2 {s}")

print("Saying hello")
func1("Tom")
func1("Dick")
func1("Harry")
          
print("\nSaying hello a second time")
func2("Tom")
func2("Dick")
func2("Harry")
```

Output:

```
Decorator 1
Saying hello
Hello 1 Tom
Hello 1 Dick
Hello 1 Harry

Saying hello a second time
Decorator 2
Hello 2 Tom
Decorator 2
Hello 2 Dick
Decorator 2
Hello 2 Harry
```

In my opinion, your script is a poor use case for a decorator in the first place.  But that's a matter of style.

Comment: As far as I understood the purpose of the decorator is just to add the function to a list, so it does not need to create a new function.

Comment: But isn't that the silliest misuse of the decorator syntax?  Why not just delete the entire definition of on_message, delete the @on_message line, and add one line `MESSAGE_LISTENERS.append(on_event)` after the definition of `on_event`?  Why have a list named MESSAGE_LISTENERS if that's the only thing you're going to put in it?  To me, it's far more likely that OP did not realize that his decorator wasn't written in the normal way.

Comment: the decorator is just fine. it just annotates the decorated function as a listener.